# How to filter out a string with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, regex-group, regex-negation

Let's say I want a regex expressing a filter selecting a string of a particular shape only if it doesn't end in a specific suffix, for example:

- `AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE` or `a1.b2.c3.d4.e5` should both pass the filter

whereas

- `AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE.writing` or `a1.b2.c3.d4.e5.writing` shouldn't due to the `.writing` suffix.

Sounds like a composite of something like `[\d\w]` with `!.writing`, but unsure how to express such a combo in a valid regex expression.

Could someone please help?

Comment: You probably want a negative lookahead for `.writing` at the end of the string i.e. `(?!.*\.writing$)`

Comment: It would be helpful to know which language you are using

Comment: @Nick I will be passing the regex to Java, but is it not language agnostic?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, not all languages support all forms of lookarounds.

Comment: You probably want something like this https://regex101.com/r/QI43Cn/1

Comment: There is no 1 correct Regex - there are many variations and slight differences between each and every regex-engine.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards
For many languages you can also get various different libraries offering different behaviour.
For java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html - it should ofer lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

your examples do not really match up.

`[\d\w]` ìs redundant:  `\d` is `[0-9]` but `\w` already is matching that with `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`,

And you say

> `AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE.writing` or `a1.b2.c3.d4.e5.writing` shouldn't due to the `.writing` suffix.

Now if you only care about if it matches or not then you can check if there is a match for the prohibited ending and negate your following logic.

```
String inputString = <your-input>;
if( Pattern.compile("\\w*\\.writing$").matcher(inputstring).matches() ) {
 // no match - so the string is "valid"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative regex:

"^(?:\w+\.)+\w+$" and "\.writing$"

Regex in testbench and context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> inputs = List.of("AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE", "a1.b2.c3.d4.e5", "AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE.writing", "a1.b2.c3.d4.e5.writing");

    for (String input: inputs) {
        printResult(input);
    }
}

private static void printResult(String input) {
    // Pattern allowedPattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\w+\\.)+\\w+$"); -> \\w will match 'A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]'
    // Pattern allowedPattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.){4}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"); -> if you know that it always going to be 4 sections with ending dot, and the last section with no dot

    Pattern allowedPattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    Pattern notAllowedSuffixPattern = Pattern.compile("\\.writing$");
    System.out.println("Incoming input: " + input);
    String result = (!notAllowedSuffixPattern.matcher(input).find() && allowedPattern.matcher(input).find())
            ? "Matching.\n"
            : "Not Matching!\n";
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
Incoming input: AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE
Matching.

Incoming input: a1.b2.c3.d4.e5
Matching.

Incoming input: AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE.writing
Not Matching!

Incoming input: a1.b2.c3.d4.e5.writing
Not Matching!
```

Answer (score -1):

With `grep`:

```
AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE
a1.b2.c3.d4.e5
AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE.writing

$ grep -v '.writing' file
AaA.BbB.CcC.DdD.EeE
a1.b2.c3.d4.e5
```